# Proving generalized Weierstrass theorem

Tags: optimization

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a lower (upper) semi-continuous function and $X$ is compact. Prove or disprove:
$$f \text{ is bounded from the top and bottom,}$$
$$\text{There exists }\min_{x\in X}f(x) \text{ and } \max_{x\in X}f(x),$$
$$\text{ For each minimizing and maximizing sequence }x_k \text{ it converges to a extremal point.}$$

First, I want to determine which of these statements hold. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Just to make sure my answer is correct: would you please rewrite your question to apply only to the case that $f$ is *lower* semi-continuous?

Answer (score 1):

I shall consider only the case that $f$ is *lower* semi-continuous, and interpret the question pertaining to this case as follows.

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a compact topological space, and let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be lower semi-continuous ($f$'s range is assumed to be equipped with the Euclidean topology). Which of the following assertions holds for sure?
>
> 1. $f$ is bounded.
> 2. $f$ attains a minimum *and* a maximum.
> 3. If $x^*$ is the limit of some minimizing sequence *or* of some maximizing sequence, then $f$ attains an extremum at $x^*$.

***Answer***

None of the assertions holds for sure.

As a counter-example, set $X := [0,1]$, define $\tau$ to be the topology induced on $[0,1]$ by the Euclidean norm, and consider the function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, defined as follows. For every $x \in X$,
 $$
 f(x) := \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{x}, & x \in (0,1], \\
 2, & x = 0.
 \end{cases}
 $$

Then $(X,\tau)$ is a compact topological space, and $f$ is lower semi-continuous, but

1. $f$ is not bounded,
2. $f$ does not attain a maximum, and
3. the harmonic sequence $h = (h_1, h_2, \dots)$, $h_n := \frac{1}{n}$, is maximizing, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(h_n) = \infty = \sup\ f(X)$, however $f$ does not attain an extremum at $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} h_n = 0$, as $\underset{=1}{f(1)} < \underset{=2}{f(0)} < \underset{=3}{f(1/3)}$.